# How to set the AttributedText to UIAlertAction in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertaction

How to display an option with UIAlertAction when it has Html tags in the text(ex: SpO<sub>2</sub>)? For a label we use attributed text. How can we set attributed text to UIAlertAction.

Comment: There is no public API in `UIAlertAction` that supports attributed text. But you can write `SpO₂` without using attributed text.

Comment: @rmaddy : Can you please let me know how we can add SpO<sub>2</sub> when the text has html tags

Comment: As I said, you can't. It's not supported. Unicode has subscripted numbers (which I show an example of in my first comment). Depending on the HTML you expect, you may be able to write code to translate HTML such as `<sub>2</sub>` into the character `₂`, for example.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks. It works for <sub>2</sub> as there is a unicode character for subscript 2. Any idea on how to get the unicode for text like P<sub>PEAK</sub> ?

Comment: There's only about 30 subscript characters in Unicode and none are the letters A-Z.